# Single clear word for 'hot food'

Tags: word-request, food

**The question**
In my native language we have two ways of saying the food is hot. One meaning spicy and one meaning too/very warm.

I am now looking for a way to use this sentence:

> The food is ...{single word here}...

I want the meaning to be clear (the food is warm to the point where caution is recommended). If there is not a single word for this that is also fine, I could then at least start looking for better workarounds.

**Thoughts so far**
I always used 'hot' but that can easily be confused with spicy so I am currently using workarounds.

'Warm' can mean 'nice and warm' or 'too warm', so I am not satisfied by that either.

Comment: You may use "oven-like" or "blazing hot".

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28199/16310

Comment: Any time I want to warn someone, I lead with a warning: "Watch out / be careful, it's still hot."

Comment: Agree with snailplane. Saying *still hot* makes it clear which sense of *hot* you're referring to.

Comment: "Haute cuisine - hot food" Alan Partridge. Sorry, probably off topic even for a comment.

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic problem in English. There is no concise, easily-recognized way to say that food is hot in the sense of the temperature being high. People often give long explanations, like, "This sausage is really hot. I mean temperature-hot, not spicy-hot."

Answer (score -1):

When you use an adjective *hot* with food, the first meaning in English that would come to my mind is, the foot is *warm* to the point (as you said). If there are lots of chillies put in it, the food becomes *spicy*.

However, the word *hot* is **also** used to say the food it spicy but then, the usage, to avoid ambiguity, could be --`The food that tastes hot OR The food very hot in taste`. [A blog from Wired](http://www.wired.com/2010/09/why-does-spicy-food-taste-hot/) reads that as the headline.

> **Why Does Spicy Food Taste Hot?**

You may use other synonyms as Lucian Sava says in addition to *scalding (mainly for liquid I guess*, boiling, [sizzling (as in a sizzling steak)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SIZZLING) etc..